# Delphi XE3 gives EFOpenError when specifying "FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE" in TFileStream's constructor

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tfilestream

Following statement runs fine under Delphi XE (Windows 7 x64) but gives "Exception class EFOpenError with message..." under Delphi XE3 (Windows 7 x64). It looks like a bug. If so, is there a workaround?

```
      TFileStream.Create(
        'C:\Test.txt'
        , fmOpenRead,
//        FILE_SHARE_READ);
//        FILE_SHARE_WRITE);
        FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fmShareDenyNone` constant instead of `FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE`:

```
 TFileStream.Create(
    'C:\Test.txt', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
```

it is not a bug. See [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TFileStream.Create) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion very much! If it is not a bug, that Delphi XE version runs fine should be wrong? Also, "fmShareDenyNone" is "4" but "FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE" is "3", do you imply these two function the same? (I think I adopted "FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE" from one SO post.)

Comment: @Xichen - fmShareDenyNone is not 4, but what difference does it make if it's 4 or something else? FILE_SHARE_.. flags are for `CreateFile`, they've got nothing to do with a TFleStream.

Comment: @XichenLi - I have no XE3, in XE the 3rd constructor parameter is simply ignored. Use 'or'ed fmShareXXX constant with 2nd parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your further comments very much!